# I have over 800 contacts in my phone, why do only 4 show up in Google Contacts?

Tags: google-contacts, synchronization

i have over 800 contacts in my phone but only 4 in Gmail.
How can I see all the contacts?

I have done the synchronization part on my phone.

Comment: What kind of phone, what kind of synchronization?

Answer (score 1):

From the information provided by you, seems to me that your contacts are local to the phone or part of a different service, not Google. When you synchronize with Google, only the Google data gets synced. Therefore, the other contacts, which are not part of Google contacts, will not be seen under your Google account. You'll have to migrate them, or copy them, to Google contacts in order to see them.